# Flutter: how to build a Widget-List-List-Widget layout?

Tags: flutter

I would like to build something like this:

Container
Container
ListView (tappable items)
ListView items based on firstListView tapped item - it is hidden until something tapped in first list
Button stick to the bottom

[image]

ListViews are ruined whatever I am trying, expanded, flex, mediaquery etc...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with the "stick to the bottom" part, but if I understand correctly, you may want to take a look at the [ExpansionPanelList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html).
Don't worry, you can customize the header to be fully tappable and hide the arrow.